# Create a ring with two different colors with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I'm trying to create a half ring like this:

[image]

I know background image or SVG may do it, but is there a pure CSS way?

I google it but only find how to create a half circle:

```css
.half-circle {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px; /* as the half of the width */
    border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border: 10px solid gray;
    border-bottom: 0;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="half-circle">
<div>
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. And yes it's possible with css.

Comment: @user5014677 sorry about the short description, I do have tried

Comment: an example that might inspire you https://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/oxZZLg

Answer (score 2):

yes it is possible through css.. here is the example

```css
   .loader {
        border-right: 16px solid #00ccff;
        border-left: 16px solid #99ff00;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 20% 45%;
        border-top: 16px solid #99ff00;
        border-bottom: 16px solid #00ccff;
        width: 120px;
        height: 120px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="loader">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this, if you want this figure static and in dynamic case you need to use javaScript.

```css
.ring-container {height: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative;}
.ring {border: 15px solid #b25912; border-radius: 100%; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;}
.ring-overlay {border: 15px solid transparent; border-top-color: #a6a6a6; border-left-color: #a6a6a6; border-radius: 100%; width: 300px; height: 300px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2; transform: rotate(200deg);}
```

```html
<div class="ring-container">
 <div class="ring">
 </div>
 <div class="ring-overlay">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried you answer, but can it represent the percentage from 0% to 100%?  I tried to rotate the element, but it seems to have a smaller range.

Comment: Yes, i tried your code.I use transform: rotate to make it dynamic,but the grey border is too short to cover the ring.

Comment: @Julien Updated my answer.

Comment: You mean rotate the element with class "ring-overlay" ? I tried, still got that problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149492/discussion-between-rohit-sharma-and-julien).